# How to apply a class method to a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, class

all I have a bunch of tweet text in a pandas column. I have made a class to process all of the various aspects of the text ie remove punctuation, expand contractions, remove special characters, etc. I have succeeded in processing individual rows with the class, however, I can't figure out how to apply the methods to the entire column of text.

```
class ProcessTweetText:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def remove_web_link(self):
        self.text = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", self.text)
        return self.text

    def remove_html(self):
        self.text = self.text.replace('\n', ' ')
        return self.text

    def replace_contractions(self):
        return contractions.fix(self.text)

    def remove_hyphen(self):
        self.text = self.text.replace('—', ' ')
        self.text = self.text.replace('-', ' ')
        return self.text

    def remove_mentions(self):
        self.text = re.sub('@[A-Za-z0-9_]\S+', '', self.text)
        return self.text

    def remove_hashtags(self):
        self.text = re.sub('#[A-Za-z0-9_]\S+', '', self.text)
        return self.text

    def remove_punctuation(self):
        self.text = ''.join([c for c in self.text if c not in string.punctuation])
        return self.text

    def remove_special_characters(self):
        self.text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]', '', self.text)
        return self.text

    def process_text(self):
        example.remove_web_link()
        example.remove_html()
        example.replace_contractions()
        example.remove_hyphen()
        example.remove_hyphen()
        example.remove_mentions()
        example.remove_hashtags()
        example.remove_punctuation()
        example.remove_special_characters()


example = ProcessTweetText(df['original_tweets'][100])
example.process_text()
example.text
```

Perhaps this is not the correct way to go about this, as I am still new to using classes. However, any help applying the desired changes to the pandas' column would be much appreciated. Thanks guys!!

Comment: Side note: you don't have to `return self.text` in all your methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your structure you can use something like this:

```
def foo(text):
    example = ProcessTweetText(text)
    example.process_text()
    return example.text

df['original_tweets'].apply(foo)
```

But actually I don't see the point of using a class for this purpose. You could simply do it like this:

```
def foo(text):
    text = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", text)
    text = text.replace('\n', ' ')
    text = text.replace('—', ' ')
    text = text.replace('-', ' ')
    text = re.sub('@[A-Za-z0-9_]\S+', '', text)
    text = re.sub('#[A-Za-z0-9_]\S+', '', text)
    text = ''.join([c for c in text if c not in string.punctuation])
    text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]', '', text)
    return text

df['original_tweets'].apply(foo)
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. Ya, the one function is what I used originally to make it work so I could complete the project, but I'm going through and cleaning and documenting everything up and I wasn't sure if packing that many changes into one function was bad form. But I guess it all falls under the "function" of cleaning text, so might not be a bad move.